# Android SQLlite database search method

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a problem with Android sqlite and cursor, I want to verify that the value entered in a text box is not in my database.

```
ContenuBDD contenuBdd = new ContenuBDD(MainActivity.this);
                contenuBdd.open();


                if(contenuBdd.recherche(text.getText().toString())== true)
                {
                    System.out.println("ok");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("not ok");

                }

                contenuBdd.close();
```

code of search method :

```
public boolean recherche(String titre){

    Cursor c = bdd.query(TABLE_CONTENU, new String[] {COL_ID, COL_VALEUR}, COL_VALEUR + " LIKE \"" + titre +"\"", null, null, null, null);
    if(c == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For now, even if I enter a value that is not in the database, "not ok" is displayed

my  request :

```
String query = new String( "select valeur from table_contenu where valeur = "+titre);
```

my logcat :

```
02-12 10:51:02.338: E/AndroidRuntime(11642): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select valeur from table_contenu where valeur =
```

Comment: You'll have to check if the cursor has content instead of it being `null`. For example use [moveToFirst](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()) - if this returns false, the cursor is empty and so has no results.

Comment: if it is null there are no content?

Comment: No, if it is `null` there must have been some serious problem with you DB. The query should always return a Cursor. But that Cursor can be empty. That would be the case if the Query does not return any results.

Comment: like this :  if(c.moveToFirst() == false )
  {
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }

Comment: it always return "true"

Comment: `return cursor.getCount() > 0`, please consider the API for simple cases as these.

Comment: If it always returns true then that's a different issue

Comment: you right my request may be a problem, but it seems normal

Comment: Concatenating the string in `query = new String( "select valeur from table_contenu where valeur = "+titre)` is an extremely severe security risk and it enables **SQL Injection**

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer to test :

```
 if(c.getCount() == 0)
```

instead of

```
  if(c == null)
```

And maybe your could manage it with a raw query like :

```
String q = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE titre = titre";
Cursor c= mDb.rawQuery(q, null);
```

Comment: i wiil try whith this : String query = new String( "select valeur from table_contenu where valeur = titre");
  Cursor c = bdd.rawQuery( query , null);

Comment: There is a problem with the request

Comment: if 'valeur' is the name of the column in the database and 'table_contenu' the name of your table, i don't know where the problem is.

Comment: My first query does not seem to work but at least it does not crash the application

Comment: For the second query the problem is coming from that your variable titre is null

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24144236/2413303

The way you're supposed to do a query is the following:

```
private String[] allColumns = { Table1.COLUMN_ID, Table1.COLUMN_NAME,
        Table1.COLUMN_OTHERCOLUMN };

public ItemDB findEmployeeById(long id)
{
    ItemDB employee = null;
    Cursor cursor = database.query(ItemTable.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, ItemTable.COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] {""+id}, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        employee = createItemFromCursor(cursor);
    }
    return employee;
}
```

Another possible way is using `rawQuery` if you need to specifically rename a column (for example, the `id` to `_id` because the adapters demand it):

```
public Cursor getRawQueryCursor()
{
    return database
            .rawQuery(
                    "SELECT id as _id, name, dateFrom || ' - ' || dateTo as date FROM " + ItemTable.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE lower(name) = ?",
                    new String[] { inputName });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, SQLite always returns a `Cursor`, but in case of nothing found, `Cursor#getCount()` will result in `0`, as displayed in the API.

Comment: I'll try with c.getCount () == 0

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(String TableName, String dbfield, String fieldValue)
    { 
         db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String Query = "Select * from " + TableName + " where " + dbfield + "="
                + fieldValue;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);

        if(cursor.getCount() <=0)
         {
             return false;
         }
             return true;
    }
```

Comment: `"Select * from " + TableName + " where " + dbfield + "=" + fieldValue;` this line is called "string concatenation" which in an SQL command if `fieldValue` is an input field from the user then it enables **SQL Injection** and is an extremely severe security risk: http://xkcd.com/327/