# Create Offline SQLite Database For Groups

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create the the database for groups page in my application. But I do not know how to create this.
This page include the two Text groups. That is my group and my secondary group. each of these two group contain spinner for selection of email id. By selecting a particular email id there are two button that are add and delete.
when I select One Id and click on add button then it is saved on server side .there is a another text view below spinner on click of which I can see that the Id is added .if this selected Id I want to add has already exist then message display.same for delete button. and same for my secondary group. Now I just want that how I create and store SQLite Database For this page so it fetch data from SQLite rather then the web server.

```
**Fragmentgroups.java**



    public class FragmentGroups extends Fragment {

         private SharedPreferences pref;
         Cursor cursor;
         ArrayList<member> membr,membr2;
         ListView list1 ;
         ListView list2 ;
         Button add,delete,add2,delete2;
         TextView gp1,gp2;
         GroupAdapter groupadapter;
         private Typeface ftype;
         SendJobDataBase db;
         FragmentDialog dialog ;
         ArrayList<String> emailArray = new ArrayList<String>();
         String memail;
         private String login_token;
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter ;
         Spinner e1,e2;
         String emails[];

         public FragmentGroups(){}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_fragment, container, false);
            e1=(Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.eemail);
            e2=(Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.eemail2); 
                     new Members().execute();
             add =(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add);
             add2 =(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add2);
             delete =(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
             delete2 =(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.delete2);
             gp1  =(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewm);
             gp2  =(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.views);
             pref=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Driver", getActivity().MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
             login_token = pref.getString("login_token","login_token"); 

            add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    new AddMembers().execute(); 
                    }           
                });

            add2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        new AddMembers2().execute();    
                        }           
                    });

            delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        new DeleteMembers().execute();  
                        }           
                    });
            delete2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        new DeleteMembers2().execute(); 
                        }           
                    });

            gp1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent =new Intent(getActivity() ,viewgroup.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                        }           
                    });

            gp2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent2 =new Intent(getActivity() ,viewsecgroup.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                        }           
                    });

             return rootView;
           }

        private class Members extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {


            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
            {
                ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
                {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    try 
                    {
                        JSONObject job= new JSONObject();
                         job.put("status_key","2");
                         job.put("method","driver_emails");
                         job.put("login_token",login_token);
                         System.out.print(login_token);


                      StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job.toString());
                      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/mobileapp_now/webservice.php");
                      httppost.setEntity(se);

                      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                      String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                      JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);
                      Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));

                        JSONArray jArray = jo.getJSONArray("all_driver_email_Ids");  
                          for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            System.out.println("please print my name...for....");
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsob = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                emailArray.add(jsob.getString("Email").toString());

                                 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.listrow, emailArray);           
                          } catch (JSONException e) {

                            } 
                        }

                        }
                catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                return params;

            }             

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
            {

                super.onPostExecute(result);
                e1.setAdapter(adapter); 
                e2.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            }   

        private class AddMembers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
            ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
            {
                ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
                {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    try 
                    {
                    JSONObject job= new JSONObject();

                        memail= e1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        System.out.println(memail);
                        memail.replace("" ,"%20");
                         job.put("email",memail);

                         job.put("status_key","2");
                         job.put("method","add_emails");
                         job.put("login_token",login_token);

                        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job.toString());
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/mobileapp_now/webservice.php");
                        httppost.setEntity(se);
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                           Log.i("response", data);

                            System.out.println("response "+data);
                                    String call;
                                    call = data;

                                    System.out.println("print me............."+call);

                                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);
                                    Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));

                                    if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
                                    {
                                        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                        alert.setTitle("Alert!!!");
                                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int whichButton) 
                                            {
                                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                    dialog.dismiss();


                                            }
                                        });
                                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {
                                                alert.show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                        alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int whichButton) {
                                                dialog.dismiss();

                                            }
                                        });
                                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                                        {
                                            public void run() 
                                            {
                                                pDialog.dismiss();

                                                alert.show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                }
                                catch (Exception e) 
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            return params;
                        }
                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
                        {

                            super.onPostExecute(result);
                        }       
            }   


        private class DeleteMembers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
            ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
            {
                ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
                {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    try 
                    {
                    JSONObject job= new JSONObject();

                        memail= e1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        System.out.println("email is " +memail);
                        memail.replace("" ,"%20");
                         job.put("email",memail);
                         job.put("status_key","2");
                         job.put("method","delete_groupemails");
                         job.put("login_token",login_token);

                        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job.toString());
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/mobileapp_now/webservice.php");
                        httppost.setEntity(se);
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                           Log.i("response", data);

                            System.out.println("response "+data);
                                    String call;
                                    call = data;

                                    System.out.println("print me............."+call);

                                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);
                                    Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));

                                    if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
                                    {
                                        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                        alert.setTitle("Alert!!!");
                                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int whichButton) 
                                            {
                                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                    dialog.dismiss();


                                            }
                                        });
                                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {
                                                alert.show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                        alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int whichButton) {
                                                dialog.dismiss();

                                            }
                                        });
                                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                                        {
                                            public void run() 
                                            {
                                                pDialog.dismiss();

                                                alert.show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                }
                                catch (Exception e) 
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            return params;
                        }
                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
                        {

                            super.onPostExecute(result);
                        }

        }   


        private class AddMembers2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
            ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
            {
                ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
                {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    try 
                    {
                    JSONObject job= new JSONObject();

                        memail= e2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        System.out.println(memail);
                        memail.replace("" ,"%20");
                         job.put("email",memail);
                         job.put("status_key","2");
                         job.put("method","add_myscndryemails");
                         job.put("login_token",login_token);

                        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job.toString());
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/mobileapp_now/webservice.php");
                        httppost.setEntity(se);
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                           Log.i("response", data);

                            System.out.println("response "+data);
                                    String call;
                                    call = data;

                                    System.out.println("print me............."+call);

                                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);
                                    Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));

                                    if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
                                    {
                                        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                        alert.setTitle("Alert!!!");
                                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int whichButton) 
                                            {
                                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                    dialog.dismiss();


                                            }
                                        });
                                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {
                                                alert.show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                        alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int whichButton) {
                                                dialog.dismiss();

                                            }
                                        });
                                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                                        {
                                            public void run() 
                                            {
                                                pDialog.dismiss();

                                                alert.show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                }
                                catch (Exception e) 
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            return params;
                        }
                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
                        {

                            super.onPostExecute(result);
                        }       
                   }    

        private class DeleteMembers2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
            ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
            {
                ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
                {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    try 
                    {
                    JSONObject job= new JSONObject();

                        memail= e2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        System.out.println("email is " +memail);
                        memail.replace("" ,"%20");
                         job.put("email",memail);

                         job.put("status_key","2");
                         job.put("method","delete_scndryemails");
                         job.put("login_token",login_token);

                        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job.toString());
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/mobileapp_now/webservice.php");
                        httppost.setEntity(se);
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                           Log.i("response", data);

                            System.out.println("response "+data);
                                    String call;
                                    call = data;

                                    System.out.println("print me............."+call);

                                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);
                                    Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));

                                    if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
                                    {
                                        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                        alert.setTitle("Alert!!!");
                                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int whichButton) 
                                            {
                                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                        });
                                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {
                                                alert.show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                        alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int whichButton) {
                                                dialog.dismiss();

                                            }
                                        });
                                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                                        {
                                            public void run() 
                                            {
                                                pDialog.dismiss();

                                                alert.show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                }
                                catch (Exception e) 
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            return params;
                        }
                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
                        {

                            super.onPostExecute(result);
                        }

        }   

    }




**GroupAdapter.java**



package com.sunmobile.navigationdrawer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class GroupAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<member> {


    GroupAdapter gdb;
    Activity activity;
    int layoutResourceId;
    member user;
    ArrayList<member> data = new ArrayList<member>();
    ListView l1;
    SendJobDataBase db;
   FragmentGroups fg;




public GroupAdapter(Activity act, int layoutResourceId,
            ArrayList<member> data) {
            super(act, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.activity = act;
            this.data = data;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }



    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        MemberHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);

        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new MemberHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user_name_txt);
        holder.delete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
        row.setTag(holder);
       } else {
    holder = (MemberHolder) row.getTag();
        }
       user = data.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(user.getName());




      holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(final View v) {


            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            adb.setTitle("Delete?");
            adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete ");
            final int user_id = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
            adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int which) {
                    // MyDataObject.remove(positionToRemove);
                    SendJobDataBase dBHandler = new SendJobDataBase(
                        activity.getApplicationContext());
                   dBHandler.Delete_Contact(user_id);


                }
                });    


            adb.show();
        }

        });  
        return row;

    }

    class MemberHolder {
        TextView name;
       Button delete;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The template I use for SQLite database interaction is the following:

The helper for creating database:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

   public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
   {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)
   {
      Table1.onCreate(database);
      Table2.onCreate(database);
      Table3.onCreate(database);
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
   {
      Table1.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
      Table2.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
      Table3.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
   }
}
```

A table as an example:

```
public class Table1
{
    public static final String TABLE_TABLE1 = "table1";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONENUMBER = "phoneNumber";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_TABLE1 + "(" 
    + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
    + COLUMN_NAME + " text not null, "
    + COLUMN_PHONENUMBER + " text not null, "
    + COLUMN_EMAIL + " text not null, "
    + ");";

    public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)
    {
       database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
       Log.w(Table1.class.getName(), "Upgrading from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
       database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TABLE1);
       onCreate(database);
    }
}
```

Operations for table:

```
public class Table1DataSource
{
    // Database fields
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private String[] allColumns = { Table1.COLUMN_ID, Table1.COLUMN_NAME,
            Table1.COLUMN_PHONENUMBER, Table1.COLUMN_EMAIL };

    public Table1DataSource(Context context)
    {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException
    {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close()
    {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    private EmployeeDB cursorToEmployee(Cursor cursor)
    {
        EmployeeDB Employee = new EmployeeDB();
        Employee.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        Employee.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        Employee.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
        Employee.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
        return Employee;
    }

    public EmployeeDB createEmployee(String name, String phoneNumber, String email)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();new
        values.put(Table1.COLUMN_NAME, name);
        values.put(Table1.COLUMN_PHONENUMBER, phoneNumber);
        values.put(Table1.COLUMN_EMAIL, email);
        long insertId = database.insert(Table1.TABLE_TABLE1, null, values);
        Cursor cursor = database.query(Table1.TABLE_TABLE1, allColumns, Table1.COLUMN_ID
                + " = " + insertId, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        EmployeeDB newEmployee = cursorToEmployee(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return newEmployee;
    }

    public void updateEmployee(EmployeeDB employee)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Table1.COLUMN_NAME, name);
        values.put(Table1.COLUMN_PHONENUMBER, phoneNumber);
        values.put(Table1.COLUMN_EMAIL, email);
        database.update(Table1.TABLE_TABLE1, values, Table1.COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[]{""+employee.getId()});
    }

    public void deleteEmployee(EmployeeDB Employee)
    {
        long id = Employee.getId();
        database.delete(EmployeeTable.TABLE_EMPLOYEE, EmployeeTable.COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }

    public Cursor getAllEmployees()
    {
        return database.query(EmployeeTable.TABLE_EMPLOYEE, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public EmployeeDB findEmployeeById(long id)
    {
        EmployeeDB employee = null;
        Cursor cursor = database.query(EmployeeTable.TABLE_EMPLOYEE, allColumns, EmployeeTable.COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] {""+id}, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            employee = cursorToEmployee(cursor);
        }
        return employee;
    }

    public List<EmployeeDB> getAllEmployeesList()
    {
        List<EmployeeDB> Employees = new ArrayList<EmployeeDB>();

        Cursor cursor = getAllEmployees();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                EmployeeDB Employee = cursorToEmployee(cursor);
                Employees.add(Employee);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return Employees;
    } 
}
```

---

---

**EDIT:** Slightly more updated version (revisited in 2017-04-29):

```
public class DatabaseManager
        extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public interface Table {
        String getTableName();

        Fields[] getFields();

        void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database);

        void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion);
    }

    public interface Fields {
        String getFieldName();

        String getFieldType();

        String getFieldAdditional();
    }

    public interface QueryDefinition {
        Cursor query(SQLiteDatabase database, Table table, String[] allFields);
    }

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final List<Table> tables;

    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DatabaseManager(Context appContext, List<Table> tables) {
        super(appContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.tables = tables;
        this.database = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        for(Table table : tables) {
            table.onCreate(database);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        for(Table table : tables) {
            table.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
        }
    }

    public interface Transaction {
        void execute(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public interface Mapper<T> {
        T from(Cursor cursor);

        ContentValues from(ContentValues contentValues, T t);
    }

    public void executeTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
        try {
            database.beginTransaction();
            transaction.execute(database);
            database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            if(database.inTransaction()) {
                database.endTransaction();
            }
        }
    }

    public <T> List<T> findAll(Table table, Mapper<T> mapper) {
        return findAll(table,
                mapper, (database, _table, allFields) -> database.query(_table.getTableName(), allFields, null, null, null, null, null));
    }

    public <T> List<T> findAll(Table table, Mapper<T> mapper, QueryDefinition queryDefinition) {
        String[] allFields = extractFieldsFromTable(table);
        Cursor cursor = queryDefinition.query(database, table, allFields);
        List<T> list = collectObjectFromCursor(mapper, cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return list;
    }

    private <T> List<T> collectObjectFromCursor(Mapper<T> mapper, Cursor cursor) {
        List<T> list = new LinkedList<>();
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                T object = mapper.from(cursor);
                list.add(object);
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(list);
    }

    @NonNull
    private String[] extractFieldsFromTable(Table table) {
        Fields[] _fields = table.getFields();
        String[] fields = new String[_fields.length];
        int i = 0;
        for(Fields field : _fields) {
            fields[i++] = field.getFieldName();
        }
        return fields;
    }
}


public abstract class BaseTable
        implements DatabaseManager.Table {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("CREATE TABLE ");
        stringBuilder.append(getTableName());
        stringBuilder.append("(");
        DatabaseManager.Fields[] fields = getFields();
        int size = fields.length;
        int i = 0;
        for(DatabaseManager.Fields field : fields) {
            stringBuilder.append(field.getFieldName());
            stringBuilder.append(" ");
            stringBuilder.append(field.getFieldType());
            stringBuilder.append(" ");
            if(field.getFieldAdditional() != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(field.getFieldAdditional());
            }
            if(i < size - 1) {
                stringBuilder.append(",");
            }
            i++;
        }
        stringBuilder.append(");");
        database.execSQL(stringBuilder.toString());
    }

    @Override // TODO: implement migration
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w("Table[" + getTableName() + "]", "Upgrading from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + getTableName());
        onCreate(database);
    }
}

public enum Tables {
    CAT(new CatTable());

    private DatabaseManager.Table table;

    Tables(DatabaseManager.Table table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    public <T extends DatabaseManager.Table> T getTable() {
        //noinspection unchecked
        return (T) table;
    }

    public static List<DatabaseManager.Table> getTables() {
        Tables[] _tables = Tables.values();
        List<DatabaseManager.Table> tables = new ArrayList<>(_tables.length);
        for(Tables table : _tables) {
            tables.add(table.table);
        }
        return tables;
    }
}

public class CatTable
        extends BaseTable {
    public static final String NAME = "cat";

    public enum Fields
            implements DatabaseManager.Fields {
        ID("_id", "text", "primary key"), //"integer", "primary key autoincrement"),
        URL("url", "text", "not null"),
        SOURCE_URL("sourceUrl", "text", "not null");

        private String fieldName;
        private String fieldType;
        private String fieldAdditional;

        Fields(String fieldName, String fieldType, String fieldAdditional) {
            this.fieldName = fieldName;
            this.fieldType = fieldType;
            this.fieldAdditional = fieldAdditional;
        }

        public String getFieldName() {
            return fieldName;
        }

        public String getFieldType() {
            return fieldType;
        }

        public String getFieldAdditional() {
            return fieldAdditional;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getTableName() {
        return NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public DatabaseManager.Fields[] getFields() {
        return Fields.values();
    }
}

public class CatMapper
        implements DatabaseManager.Mapper<Cat> {
    @Override
    public Cat from(Cursor cursor) {
        return Cat.create(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    }

    @Override
    public ContentValues from(ContentValues contentValues, Cat cat) {
        contentValues.put(CatTable.Fields.ID.getFieldName(), cat.id());
        contentValues.put(CatTable.Fields.URL.getFieldName(), cat.url());
        contentValues.put(CatTable.Fields.SOURCE_URL.getFieldName(), cat.sourceUrl());
    }
}

public class CatDao {
    CatTable catTable;

    CatMapper catMapper;

    DatabaseManager databaseManager;

    public CatDao(CatTable catTable, CatMapper catMapper, DatabaseManager databaseManager) {
        this.catTable = catTable;
        this.catMapper = catMapper;
        this.databaseManager = databaseManager;
    }

    public List<Cat> findAll() {
        return databaseManager.findAll(catTable, catMapper);
    }

    public void insert(List<Cat> cats) {
        databaseManager.executeTransaction(sqLiteDatabase -> {
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            for(Cat cat : cats) {
                contentValues = mapper.from(contentValues, cat);
                sqLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(catTable.getTableName(), null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
            }
        });
    }
}

@AutoValue
public abstract class Cat {
    public abstract String id();

    public abstract String url();

    public abstract String sourceUrl();

    public static Cat create(String id, String url, String sourceUrl) {
        return new AutoValue_Cat.Builder().setId(id).setUrl(url).setSourceUrl(sourceUrl).build();
    }

    public Builder toBuilder() {
        return new AutoValue_Cat.Builder(this);
    }

    @AutoValue.Builder
    public abstract static class Builder {
        public abstract Builder setId(String id);

        public abstract Builder setUrl(String url);

        public abstract Builder setSourceUrl(String sourceUrl);

        public abstract Cat build();
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone knows how to upgrade *properly* though, I'm curious, considering dropping and recreating isn't cool in a production environment.

Comment: How many tables does your actual DB have, b/c once mine hit like 10-15 and i didn't wrap the create table commands in a single transaction it took a while (30-60 sec) to execute them, maybe longer, its been a while.

Comment: +1 for pointing me to SQLiteDatabase. I reinvented this wheel partially.

Comment: So far, I haven't needed many (currently I manipulated only 5 max, and they didn't have much data), so after a while this is probably not as scalable. Also, indexing the columns with getLong(0) rather than getLong(getColumnIndex(Table1.ID)) might be less changeable. The only interesting thing I had to do so far was create a DataSource that was independent from one *specific* table, because I had to join them. I'm fairly new to actual SQLite dev myself, but this is how I learned how to do it. :D

Comment: This seriously needs a metamodel so that you can make the whole thing generic, I admit.

Comment: Well, here's a metamodel based on the original...

Comment: https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html