# How to save Shared Preference values even device goes to off?

Tags: android

I am using `SharedPreferences` to save the server data in local, when device goes to off state the values in `SharedPreferences` were lost, again its downloading from the server.

```
public void saveCollection(Context context)
{
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.restore_values), 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor e = settings.edit();
    e.clear();
    e.putStringSet(context.getString(R.string.collection), collection);
    e.commit();
}
```

I had done this, but no luck.

Comment: How do you know they aren't saving? You may need to post the code where you are trying to retrieve them because they **will** store the values when the device is off if you've done it properly.

Comment: Are you sure this shouldn't be stored in SQLite?  Just wondering.
SQLite example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142830/create-offline-sqlite-database-for-groups/24144236#24144236

Also, I'm not sure if the Preferences you obtain are actually Application-specific. Try opening SharedPreferences from ApplicationContext.

Comment: Now, by "device goes to off", I assume you mean sleep mode, correct?

Comment: @AndrewSchuster Not really it is to be mentioned as Shutdown

Comment: Do you turn it off in the middle of the running app?

Comment: In Middle of app means ? Terminating and Shutdown

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not supply the necessary code to provide a clear solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not accessing the correct preferences:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

(assuming "this" is a context)

Answer (score 0):

Every activity goes through a very specific life-cycle as defined in [the developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html).  After reading it, you may come to find that every time an `Activity` is taken from focus, it will call the built-in `onPause()` method.  With that in mind, you can add to your activity the following:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // You can call saveCollection() here and now it will always be called when
    // the activity is taken away (assuming your app doesn't force close)
    saveCollection(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use this method to get the SharedPreferences object :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

And I think you should call saveCollection() in onPause()

Answer (score -3):

Shared preferences are always stored on the filesystem, so they're always saved when the device is turned off.  Your problem is more likely to be in reading them in than in not storing them-  especially since you aren't just opening the default shared preference for the app.

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer? If so, I am missing the answer.

Comment: Not at all.  He stated when the device is turned off he loses his shared preferences.  I'm saying there's no way that happened, he's probably reading them in wrong on relaunch.

Comment: And still your "answer" does not provide any knowledge about how to read them. Stating that he just "does something wrong" and saying one of his assumptions is not correct is barely a qualification for your text. I would rather see that as a comment and not an answer. Therefore I recommend to change it or I will flag it and the community will decide.