# error while database creation

Tags: android, sqlite

whenever i am trying to create this database it is giving an error that table ex_bottom does not exist.what's wrong?
here's my code--

DB_excercise_bottom class-->

```
 package db;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DB_Handler_exercise_bottom extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "exercise_items";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    //table name
    private static final String TABLE_EXERCISE_BOTTOM = "exercise_bottom";
    //column name
    private static final String KEY_EX_ID = "ex_id";
    private static final String KEY_EX_NAME = "ex_name";
    private static final String KEY_EX_NICKNAME = "ex_nickname";
    private static final String KEY_NO_VARIATION = "ex_variation";

    public DB_Handler_exercise_bottom(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String CREATE_TABLE_BOTTOM="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_EXERCISE_BOTTOM+ "(" + KEY_EX_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_EX_NAME + " TEXT," +KEY_EX_NICKNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_NO_VARIATION + " INTEGER" +")";  
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BOTTOM);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public int getRecordCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EXERCISE_BOTTOM;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return count;
    }
public void addData(Table_exercise_bottom bottom){
SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_EX_ID, bottom.getEx_id());
values.put(KEY_EX_NAME, bottom.getEx_name());
values.put(KEY_EX_NICKNAME, bottom.getEx_nickname());
values.put(KEY_NO_VARIATION, bottom.getEx_variation());
db.insert(TABLE_EXERCISE_BOTTOM, null, values);
db.close();
}
public ArrayList<Table_exercise_bottom> getAllData() {
    ArrayList<Table_exercise_bottom> ex_bottom_list = new ArrayList<Table_exercise_bottom>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EXERCISE_BOTTOM;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Table_exercise_bottom ex_bottom=new Table_exercise_bottom();
            ex_bottom.setEx_id(cursor.getInt(0));
            ex_bottom.setEx_name(cursor.getString(1));
            ex_bottom.setEx_nickname(cursor.getString(2));
            ex_bottom.setEx_variation(cursor.getInt(3));
            // Adding data to list
            ex_bottom_list.add(ex_bottom);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());// return data list
    }
    return ex_bottom_list;
}
}


table_excercise_bottom class---->

    package db;

    public class Table_exercise_bottom {
        int ex_id,ex_variation;
        String ex_name,ex_nickname;


        public Table_exercise_bottom() {
        }
        public int getEx_id() {
            return ex_id;
        }
        public void setEx_id(int ex_id) {
            this.ex_id = ex_id;
        }
        public int getEx_variation() {
            return ex_variation;
        }
        public void setEx_variation(int ex_variation) {
            this.ex_variation = ex_variation;
        }
        public String getEx_name() {
            return ex_name;
        }
        public void setEx_name(String ex_name) {
            this.ex_name = ex_name;
        }
        public String getEx_nickname() {
            return ex_nickname;
        }
        public void setEx_nickname(String ex_nickname) {
            this.ex_nickname = ex_nickname;
        }
        public Table_exercise_bottom(int ex_id, String ex_name,
                String ex_nickname,int ex_variation) {
            this.ex_id = ex_id;
            this.ex_variation = ex_variation;
            this.ex_name = ex_name;
            this.ex_nickname = ex_nickname;
        }


    }
```

splash activity-->(here i'am trying to add data to the table)

```
  package com.example.fitnessapp;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import constants.Const_String_Food;
    import db.DB_Handler_exercise_bottom;
    import db.DB_Handler_food;
    import db.DB_Handler_exercise_top;
    import db.Table_exercise_bottom;
    import db.Table_exercise_top;
    import db.Table_items;

    public class Splash_Activity extends Activity {
        public static final int Splash_Time=3000;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Splash_Activity.this,Main_Screen.class);
                    DB_Handler_food db1 = new DB_Handler_food(Splash_Activity.this);
                    Const_String_Food con=new Const_String_Food();
                    if(db1.getRecordCount()==0){
                        //adding data in database food
                        db1.addData(new Table_items("Eggs",con.egg_benefits , con.egg_positives,"eggs" ));
                        db1.addData(new Table_items("Brown Rice",con.brown_rice_benefits,con.brown_rice_positives,"brown_rice"));
                        db1.addData(new Table_items("Black Beans",con.black_beans_benefits,con.black_beans_positives,"black_beans"));
                        db1.addData(new Table_items("Oats",con.oats_benefits,con.oats_positives,"oats"));
                        db1.addData(new Table_items("Avocados",con.avocados_benefits,con.avocados_positives,"avocado"));
                        db1.addData(new Table_items("Salmon",con.salmon_benefits,con.salmon_positives,"salmon"));
                        db1.addData(new Table_items("Blueberries",con.blueberries_benefits,con.blueberries_positives,"black_berry"));
                        db1.addData(new Table_items("Broccoli",con.broccoli_benefits,con.broccoli_positives,"brocolli"));
                        db1.addData(new Table_items("Pears",con.pears_benefits,con.pears_positives,"pears"));
                    }
                    DB_Handler_exercise_top db2=new DB_Handler_exercise_top(Splash_Activity.this);
                    if(db2.getRecordCount()==0){
                        //adding data in database exercise_top
                        db2.addData(new Table_exercise_top(1,"Presses","",0));
                        db2.addData(new Table_exercise_top(2,"Triceps","",2));
                        db2.addData(new Table_exercise_top(3,"Bicepts","",2));
                        db2.addData(new Table_exercise_top(4,"Bridge","",0));
                        db2.addData(new Table_exercise_top(5,"Plank","",0));
                        db2.addData(new Table_exercise_top(6,"Shoulders","",0));
                        db2.addData(new Table_exercise_top(7,"Chest","",2));
                        db2.addData(new Table_exercise_top(8,"Back","",0));
                    }
                    DB_Handler_exercise_bottom db3=new DB_Handler_exercise_bottom(Splash_Activity.this);
                    if(db3.getRecordCount()==0){
                        //adding data in database exercise_bottom
                        db3.addData(new Table_exercise_bottom(1,"Squats","",3));
                        db3.addData(new Table_exercise_bottom(2,"leg lifts","",3));
                        db3.addData(new Table_exercise_bottom(3,"lunges","",3));
                        db3.addData(new Table_exercise_bottom(4,"Inner thighs","",0));
                        db3.addData(new Table_exercise_bottom(5,"Roll Ups","",2));
                        db3.addData(new Table_exercise_bottom(6,"Side Situps","",0));
                        db3.addData(new Table_exercise_bottom(7,"bicycle","",3));
                    }
                    DB_exercise_cardio db4=new DB_exercise_cardio(Splash_Activity.this);
                    if(db4.getRecordCount()==0){
                        //adding data in database exercise_cardio
                        db4.addData(new Table_exercise_cardio(1,"Walk","",0));
                    db4.addData(new Table_exercise_cardio(2,"Taps","",0));
                    db4.addData(new Table_exercise_cardio(3,"Step","",0));
                    db4.addData(new Table_exercise_cardio(4,"Knee Lifts","",0));
                    db4.addData(new Table_exercise_cardio(5,"Boxing","",0));
                    db4.addData(new Table_exercise_cardio(6,"Dance","",0));

                    }
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            },Splash_Time);
        }

    }






logs---->

    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241): Process: com.example.fitnessapp, PID: 20241
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: exercise_bottom (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM exercise_bottom
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at db.DB_Handler_exercise_bottom.getRecordCount(DB_Handler_exercise_bottom.java:42)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at com.example.fitnessapp.Splash_Activity$1.run(Splash_Activity.java:60)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    07-22 13:08:32.826: E/AndroidRuntime(20241):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If you recently added this Column then you must uninstall your app and run again new apk built so that older DB getting delete and Newer DB is create.....

Comment: it worked and created first two tables,but while 3rd table(excercise_top) it gives an error.I am uploading the logs

Comment: change database version to 2 and create an onUpgrade() implementation that will create the new table

Comment: @Zhuinden just one problem that it creates database for first time but whenever i run my app again it gives an error saying database cannot be degrade from version 4 to 1

Comment: did you actually change `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;` to `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;`? It should work.

Comment: @Zhuinden yes i did that and it worked for the first time the app is run or whenever i uninstall the app and install it again, that above error is recieved whenever i try to run the installed app again

Comment: You are probably calling something somewhere that you shouldn't. This is the database SQLite template I use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24144236/2413303

Comment: @Zhuinden i wrote all my create query in one class instead of creating separate classes and separate database versions.Now it's working fine for me :)